# How to show percentage of average GPA > 3.5?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a query that shows the GPA of students, but I'm not sure how to show the percentage of students that have a GPA > 3.5.

```
SELECT avg(Grade) as GPA, studentID from tblTranscript
GROUP BY studentID
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply, `having` is wizard:

```
SELECT avg(Grade) as GPA, studentID from tblTranscript
GROUP BY studentID
HAVING avg(Grade) > 3.5
```

Comment: Yes this shows GPA > 3.5 but how do I get a percentage. Do I need to take the results of this with a count statement and then divide it by the total amount of students?

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps.

```
SELECT avg(Grade) as GPA, studentID from tblTranscript
GROUP BY studentID HAVING avg(Grade)>3.5;
```

Comment: I need to take the results of this query and divide it by the total amount of students to get the percentage?

Comment: it  seems percentage formula should be like
(sum(Grade)/(count(*) * 4))*100).

Answer (score 0):

This works:

```
SELECT  
    (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM (
        SELECT * FROM (
            SELECT AVG(Grade) as GPA, studentID 
            FROM tblTranscript
            GROUP BY studentID
        ) AS a 
        WHERE a.GPA > 3.5
    ) as d) 
    /
    (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM (
        SELECT * 
        FROM tblTranscript 
        GROUP BY studentID
    ) as e)
AS percentage
```

Where my `tblTranscript` is:

```
CREATE TABLE `tbltranscript` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `studentID` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Grade` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

Comment: @ChaCol, could you test this and see if it works? I tested locally and it appears to work.

Comment: I try to run it and it says Cannot group on fields select with *

Comment: Can you please provide example table / table data and which version of MySQL you are using? This works fine for me in MySQL 5.7.

Comment: SectionID StudentID Grade
1 11888961         3.5
1 18421330 3.5
1 23210862 3.5
1 26611383         3.5
1 27081228 2
1 33120006 3.5
1 39203408 3.5

Comment: StudentID DeptID Name Sex Class Type Email Address DOB
10100118 ECE Jonathan , Bueno M Sophomore Full Time Jonathan.Bueno@univ.edu Colony Ct.Lindenhurst 5/12/1974
10336702 CIS Jonathan , Coleman III M Senior Full Time Jonathan.Coleman@univ.edu UnknownWaukegan 11/21/1980
10379308 CIS Jonathan , Carlson M Graduate Full Time Jonathan.Carlson@univ.edu 24th PlaceNorth Chicago 3/17/1978
10871990 CAPP Neil , Coble M Senior Full Time Neil.Coble@univ.edu GreenfieldNorth Chicago 4/11/1976
11110764 CAPP Neil , Bess M Senior Full Time

Comment: Sorry that's all jambled up but I'm also using Access

Comment: @ChaCol, you've tagged this question SQL and MySQL. Are you using MySQL/SQL or are you using Access?

Comment: Sorry I didn't know there was a difference

Comment: @ChaCol there is, I suggest you do some research and then either retag this question or delete and re-ask with the correct tags.